# Laravel 5.5 - Job - Trigger failed() method with "GuzzleHttp\Exception"

Tags: php, guzzle, laravel-5.5

I'm building a simple Laravel Job that send a GET request with `GuzzleHttp\Client` to a remote web service. 
When the `GuzzleHttp` request return an error, it throw an instance of `GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException` but the `failed()` method must be an instance of `app\Jobs\Exception`.
This is the code:

```
namespace app\V1\Jobs;
class setRegionJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    // . . .
    public function handle()
    {
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
            'base_uri' => 'http://link_to_api/'),
            'timeout'  => 2.0,
        ]);
        $res = $client->request('GET', '?key=param1&key2=param2');
        if ($res->getStatusCode() == 200) {
            $data = json_decode($res->getBody(), true)['data'];
        } else {
            $data = null;
        }
    }

    public function failed(Exception $exception)
    {
         // do something
    }
}
```

Then, when the `$client->request('GET', '?key=param1&key2=param2')` throw an Exception the ERROR is:

```
[2017-11-09 14:38:40] local.ERROR: Type error: Argument 1 passed to app\Jobs\setRegionJob::failed() must be an instance of app\Jobs\Exception, instance of GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException given.
```

How I can trigger the `failed()` method?

Comment: Put `use Exception;` at the top after the namespace declaration

Comment: Thank you!!! It works! The Laravel guide was clear: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#cleaning-up-after-failed-jobs